# Implementing a Descending Quicksort in C

Tags: c, quicksort

I need to implement a quicksort (in descending order) in C, but I'm having a bit of trouble-  especially with the logic. I'm trying to modify some old code I've had from from an ascending quicksort implementation in C++. The code seems to always return the input exactly, so where's the logical error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 4

int Array[MAX_SIZE];

void swap(int one, int two) {
    int temp = Array[one];
    Array[one] = Array[two];
    Array[two] = temp;
}

int partition(int left, int right, int pivot) {
    int leftPointer = left - 1;
    int rightPointer = right;
    while (Array[++leftPointer] < pivot) {
    }
    while (rightPointer > 0 && Array[--rightPointer] < pivot) {
        if (leftPointer >= rightPointer) {
            break;
        } else {
            swap(leftPointer, rightPointer);
            swap(leftPointer, right);
        }
    }
    return leftPointer;
}

void Quicksort(int left, int right) {
    if (right - left <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int pivot = Array[right];
        int PartitionPoint = partition(left, right, pivot);
        Quicksort(left, PartitionPoint - 1);
        Quicksort(PartitionPoint + 1, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    printf("\nGive values");
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &Array[i]);
    }
    Quicksort(0, MAX_SIZE - 1);
    printf("\nOutput: ");
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", Array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return 0;` in `Quicksort` --> `return ;`

Comment: I think there is a problem with the logic of `partition`. At least the pivot (`Array[MAX_SIZE-1]`) value will not be exchanged

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The `partition` function should iterate until `leftPointer` becomes larger than `rightPointer`.
- the first `while` loop should skip larger elements, not smaller elements.
- swapping the `right` element should be moved to the end of the `partition` function.
- since `partition` assumes the pivot to be at the `right` index, it would be better to not pass the pivot value as an argument.
- `Quicksort()` should not return a value.
- To avoid global variables, the array `Array` should defined locally in `main` and passed as an argument to the functions.

Here is a corrected version that optionally accepts argument values on the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int Array[], int one, int two) {
    int temp = Array[one];
    Array[one] = Array[two];
    Array[two] = temp;
}

int partition(int Array[], int left, int right) {
    int pivot = Array[right];
    int leftPointer = left - 1;
    int rightPointer = right;
    for (;;) {
        while (Array[++leftPointer] > pivot) {
        }
        while (rightPointer > 0 && Array[--rightPointer] < pivot) {
        }
        if (leftPointer >= rightPointer) {
            break;
        } else {
            swap(Array, leftPointer, rightPointer);
        }
    }
    /* move pivot to partition point */
    swap(Array, leftPointer, right);
    return leftPointer;
}

void Quicksort(int Array[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int PartitionPoint = partition(Array, left, right);
        Quicksort(Array, left, PartitionPoint - 1);
        Quicksort(Array, PartitionPoint + 1, right);
    }
}

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, n;
    int Array[MAX_SIZE];

    if (argc > 1) {
        for (n = 0; n < MAX_SIZE && n < argc - 1; n++) {
            Array[n] = strtol(argv[n + 1], NULL, 0);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Give values: ");
        for (n = 0; n < MAX_SIZE; n++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &Array[n]) != 1)
                break;
        }
    }

    Quicksort(Array, 0, n - 1);
    printf("\nOutput: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", Array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```